# Doxygen and Assembly Language

Tags: documentation, assembly, doxygen

I'd like to use Doxygen to document legacy code that's a mix of C and x86 assembly language. The assembly language is not inline, but in separate assembly-only files. How can I document the assembly language portion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See question 12 of the [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html).  Are you dealing with pure assembly files, or inline assembly inside C sources?  Assuming the former, you'll have to either write an input filter to transform the assembly code into something C-like (easier), or write a new parser (much harder).

Comment: -1
down vote
This post is quite old. I am wondering, if somebody has already found a nice and elegant solution to include assembly code into Doxygen's documentation?

The current state:

There was a Doxygen filter available that converted the provided assembly code into C-like structured code. Unforunately, the link to the filter (http://bogdro.ciki.me/inne/asm4doxy.txt) is down.
Help is appreciated

Comment: The assembly helper, asm4doxy.pl, including Ida-Pro formatting is now on github at https://github.com/rfoos/doxygen.

Answer (score 6):

Question 12 of the Doxygen FAQ eventually led me to a [Perl filter](http://rudy.mif.pg.gda.pl/~bogdro/inne/asm4doxy.txt) that looks promising. It converts the assembly code into something C-like that Doxygen can parse. Thanks!

The original [link](http://rudy.mif.pg.gda.pl/~bogdro/inne/asm4doxy.txt) appears to be dead. However back in 2008, I had pulled down a copy of **asm4doxy.pl** and squirreled it away. I've put it up on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z3ZmaEmU) if anyone is still interested. As I recall, I tried it, but it didn't really work for me at the time, but YMMV.

Comment: Note: I stored the Pastebin link to the [WayBack-Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20160422133219/http://pastebin.com/Z3ZmaEmU)